# How to enable Apache DIGEST Authentivation everywhere on files and subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I'm trying many different configurations following many tutorials and documentations, I can't get the authentication without creating thousands .htaccess files.

Here is my configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 DocumentRoot /home/user/www
 ServerName preprod.user.com
 <Directory /home/user/www>
     Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
     AllowOverride All
     AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
     Require all granted
 </Directory>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/private/preprod.user.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/preprod.user.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

And at the root level, I wrote this /home/user/www/.htaccess file :

```
 AuthType DIGEST
 AuthName "preproduction"
 AuthDigestNonceLifetime 1
 AuthDigestDomain "/home/user/www/" "https://preprod.user.com/"
 AuthDigestProvider file
 AuthUserFile "/web/auth/.digest_pw"
 Require valid-user
```

The result is :

```
https://preprod.user.com/ asks for a password
https://preprod.user.com/v1/ asks for a password
```

BUT :

```
https://preprod.user.com/v1/index.php <strong>doesn't ask for password</strong>
```

Thank you all

Comment: do you have other .htaccess who could cut the auth system ?

Comment: Can't I forbid the Auth Override ?

Comment: I dont have a .htaccess in the v1 folder

Comment: i think it come from AuthDigestDomain https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#authdigestdomain try to remove "/home/user/www/" causse it accept only uri, if it still dont work add "/v1/" as uri

Comment: Actually it is just the index.php on which it fails. I edited the end on Answer. @Froggiz, I removed /home.... Still the same, with /v1/ ... the same.

Comment: I Found the solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution :

The problem comes from the files : without telling the files the Authentication applies, it only applies on the directories and files keep served !

```
<Files *>
         AuthType DIGEST
         AuthName "preproduction"
         AuthDigestNonceLifetime 1
         AuthDigestDomain "https://preprod.user.com/"
         AuthDigestProvider file
         AuthUserFile "/web/auth/.digest_pw"
         Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Bye !